# Flip ViewPager like a ViewFlipper, possible?

Tags: android, android-viewpager, viewflipper

I want to add flipping animation for viewpager, I am able to swipe the views but I also need to flip the view.

Any pointer?

Answer (score 1):

Use [JazzyViewPager](https://github.com/jfeinstein10/JazzyViewPager) instead of the regular ViewPager. You get a lot of cool built-in animations including flip animation.

You can also just go through the source and implement your flip animation using a [PageTransformer](http://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer).

Comment: JazzyViewPager is a library. I dont want to add a library for this small thing. I am also not looking for lot of animation just simple flip animation. this will add unnecessary header to my project

Comment: That's why the second option. Go through the source and implement your own animation if you don't want the whole library.